# How to completely disable Interactive Windows popping up when running .py files in VS Code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

When running Python scripts using the "play button" at the top right, it opens up the Interactive Window and then runs the file. I hate this and want it disabled. When I disable Jupyter extension, the play button completely disappears. But at the same time I want .ipynb support for running jupyter notebooks. My VS Code looks like the below:

[VS Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuKbV.png)

update: I am getting the following message when hitting shift+enter:

command 'python.execSelectionInTerminal' not found

How to disable .py files from running the code in an interactive window?

Comment: Sounds like you have some setting changed because it should use the integrated VSCode terminal by default. At least, mine does

Comment: Also, this shouldnt change how `.ipynb` files run...

Comment: I did a 100% uninstall and reinstall of vs code and still the same issue. The only reason I brought up .ipynb files is because someone said this issue is related to the Jupyter vs code extension

Comment: VScode persists settings in your Users folder, so uninstalling wont delete that. I Jupyter extension as well, and I have never noticed a pop-up terminal when running Python scripts... Although, I haven't used my Windows machine for development in a few months

Comment: I deleted all of those folders, followed instructions here to do a complete uninstall: https://debug.to/1074/how-to-uninstall-vs-code-completely

Comment: This has still not been resolved. A few weeks ago, after clean installing vs code multiple time, I isolated this issue to an extension (although I can’t remember which one). I need this extension, but seems to change the run file button to run file in interactive window. If I remember correctly it might have been GitHub extension for some odd reason

Answer (score 0):

The play button has a memory feature, when you click the button it will use the last command you selected.

Now on my machine it includes four options

[image]

- `Run Code` is the option brought by the **Code Runner** extension
- `Run Python File` will execute the script and output the result in the integrated terminal
- `Debug Python File` will start debugging the script
- `Run Current File in Interactive Window` will run code in a interactive window

I guess you selected `Run Current File in Interactive Window` when executing the script one time, after that you didn't select it again, but clicked the play button directly, so it will use the `Run Current File in Interactive Window` option to execute the script.

The solution is very simple, you just need to select `Run Python File` in the options to execute the script.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. I do not have a dropdown like you have on the play button. Also Code Runner is not available in virtual workspaces. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you show your interface and tell me how you do it? Have you installed the Python extension?

Comment: Not sure how to share an image in a comment. But yes I have the Python extension and am able to run the .py file. Just when I do run it, it opens up an interactive window as opposed out-putting the results to the terminal like I am used to.

Comment: You can directly edit your question to add more information. Try disabling Jupyter extensions and see what happens.

Comment: Disabling Jupyter extension completely took the play button away.

Comment: Edit your question, show your question interface and operation steps. and extension interface.

Comment: Are you sure you have the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension installed?  Did you disable it?

Comment: I do have the Python extension installed and enabled

Comment: Please edit the question to show more details

Comment: I edited my post to include an image of my VS Code App

Comment: Can you show your settings.json file?